# Let $A$ and $B$ be $n\times n$ matrices. Suppose $A$ is similar to $B$. Prove trace($A$) = trace($B$).

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ and $B$ be $n\times n$ matrices. Suppose $A$ is similar to $B$. Prove $\operatorname{trace}(A) = \operatorname{trace}(B)$.

I'm not sure where to go on this. So far I have this:

If $A$ is similar to $B$, then

> $B=P^{-1}AP$ and $A=PBP^{-1}$

This implies that:

> $\operatorname{trace}(B) = \operatorname{trace}(P^{-1}AP)$ and $\operatorname{trace}(A) = \operatorname{trace}(PBP^{-1})$

Not sure where to go from here

Comment: $tr(XY) = tr(YX)$

Comment: $trace(B)=trace(P^{-1}AP)=trace(PP^{-1}A)=trace(IA)=trace(A)$.

Comment: @Jacob Mayle - How does trace($P^{-1}AP$) = trace($PP^{-1}A$)?

Comment: @EW-CodeMonkey Take a look at my answer for details. Turns out that I did it slightly differently between the comment and my answer, but it is exactly the same idea. It uses the fact that tr(AB)=tr(BA).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Because $A$ and $B$ are similar, we know that $B=P^{-1}AP$. Thus

$$tr(B)=tr(P^{-1}AP)=tr(P^{-1}(AP))=tr((AP)P^{-1})=tr(A(PP^{-1}))=tr(AI)=tr(A)$$

Comment: OH I SEE! You are using trace(AB) = trace(BA) to switch terms there! Bravo, and thanks for the help! Answer accepted!

Answer (score 9):

Use the fact that $\operatorname{trace}(AB) = \operatorname{trace}(BA)$.